# View Controller not conforming to protocol, even though all methods are implemented

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have added the library [MBDocCapture](https://github.com/iMhdi/MBDocCapture) to my project using CocoaPods. Now, as its readme suggests, I made my view controller conform to `ImageScannerControllerDelegate` and added all 4 protocol methods to my code:

```
extension DocumentUploaderViewController: ImageScannerControllerDelegate {
    func imageScannerController(_ scanner: ImageScannerController, didFinishScanningWithResults results: ImageScannerResults) {
        scanner.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func imageScannerController(_ scanner: ImageScannerController, didFinishScanningWithPage1Results page1Results: ImageScannerResults, andPage2Results page2Results: ImageScannerResults) {
        scanner.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func imageScannerControllerDidCancel(_ scanner: ImageScannerController) {
        scanner.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func imageScannerController(_ scanner: ImageScannerController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        scanner.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Now, Xcode (10.2.1) complains that I'm still missing some protocol stubs:

> Type 'DocumentUploaderViewController' does not conform to protocol 'ImageScannerControllerDelegate'
>   Do you want to add protocol stubs?

When I press `Fix`, Xcode adds the `didFailWithError` method:

```
func imageScannerController(_ scanner: ImageScannerController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
}
```

...and then complains that I have added an invalid redeclaration of the method (because it was already there!):

> Invalid redeclaration of 'imageScannerController(_:didFailWithError:)'

I have already tried:

- build
- clean derived data
- clean & build
- quit Xcode, clean, build
- reboot my Mac (10.14.3), open Xcode, clean, build

None of these tries helped.
Any ideas?

Comment: add some additional code.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik what additional code should I post? There's no other code that I'd consider relevant to this question.

Comment: i think its only matter of version can you please tell me the swift version of  MBDocCapture  you are using ? and swift version for your project ?

Comment: also can you post the function too that shows redeclaration error ?

Comment: @AbuUlHassan my project is using Swift 4. MBDocCapture 0.1.1 uses Swift 4.2, however, the example project also uses Swift 4. Xcode tries to re-add the `didFailWithError` method and, hence, throws the redeclaration error on that method after added.

Comment: please add method that show redeclaration error too.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan it's already shown in my question. Or what else do you mean?

Comment: i want to see method after stubbing ... can you do that ?

Comment: you shown Invalid redeclaration of 'imageScannerController(_:didFailWithError:)'  this, its not complete method

Comment: @AbuUlHassan I see. So I removed all my code inside the extension. Then, Xcode suggested adding missing protocol stubs. That's the code shown above. Then, Xcode complains about the missing method and upon pressing *Fix*, Xcode adds the didFailWithError method.

Comment: huff just stub it when it show redeclaration error simple copy it and paste in your question.

Comment: I've updated my post. @AbuUlHassan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192371/discussion-between-abu-ul-hassan-and-linusgeffarth).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have an `Error` model (struct or class) defined in your project explicitly which is causing this issue.

To fix this, you have two options:

1. rename your model, like `MyError`
2. or change the method's declaration to `didFailWithError error: Swift.Error`

This error always appears when there is a conflict in the scope of the model. Current delegate stubs written for `extension DocumentUploaderViewController: ImageScannerControllerDelegate` are considering the `Error` model of your project defined in local scope, while the delegate stub expects the `Error` model defined in Swift.

Comment: Amazing catch! I indeed have an `Error` model in my project. I changed the method to `didFailWithError error: Swift.Error` and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for the method in the entire project, this kind of error usually occurs when functions have similar names or are declared twice.
2. Check if you have set the delegate to the appropriate view controller. Something like:

   `let scannerViewController = ImageScannerController()`

   `scannerViewController.imageScannerDelegate = self`

Comment: I let Xcode auto-complete add the methods for me, so the names are definitely identical. I have also set the delegate, but it won't even compile...

Answer (score -2):

Dont add methods manually. Remove all methods & when the xcode complains - "Type 'DocumentUploaderViewController' does not conform to protocol 'ImageScannerControllerDelegate'
Do you want to add protocol stubs?"

Simply click fix. And you are done .

Comment: xcode sometimes does that . And one more thing after adding protocol methods ctrl+B project.

Comment: I explained in my post that I did this and it complained about a redeclaration. Hence, the method names are all correct.

Comment: I read your post , and i have faced this a issue a 100 times. this always fix this

Comment: I know that this usually fixes the issue, but this time it doesn't, which is the reason why I posted this seemingly stupid question in the first place.

Comment: In that case you can clean the derived data and try again